# Vertical centering an image in a smaller div (multiple scaled images, multiple divs)

Tags: css, image, html, vertical-alignment

I have two images.  One is 630x419; the other is 200x300.

I have each of these images displayed inside a container div with a fixed width on the container.  I'm scaling the images to width: 100% inside the container div.  Both images scale to fill the div width, but the image that is taller than it is wide (200x300) overflows down past the bottom of the div container.  I have set the overflow to hidden, but what I would like to do is vertically center the image in the div so that I can see the center of the image instead of the top of the image without messing up the scaling or display of the first image.

JSFiddle example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/P7xNg/1/

```css
.container {
  padding: 9px;
  border: 1px solid #B8B8B8;
  width: 262px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.image-box {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 172px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-box">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lG43Qgd.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">    
  <div class="image-box">
    <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bMfYu6M.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.image-box {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 172px;
    position: relative;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     overflow: hidden;

}
.image-box img {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/P7xNg/2/

Comment: With this method surely you will be hiding the bottom of the image and not the top?

Comment: This actually worked great.  Exactly what I was looking to do.  The second image is vertically centered and the top image is unmodified even when applying the same CSS to each image.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

A nice simple solution for you here.

All you have to do is instead of using the img tag create a div at the size you want the image to be. For example; 200px x 200px. Then allocate the image you want to use as a background image to that div, and then offset the image by -100px for example.

An inline example below:

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="image-box">
        <div style="width:100%;height:200px;background-image:url(my-image.jpg);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:-100px 0px;
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for this.  Background-image was one of the items I did see mentioned in my search prior to posting my question.  It seems rather verbose, but I may dive into this solution if that is all I can do.

Answer (score 0):

You are dealing with two very different image orientations. The first one is landscape in nature, and scales fine given the container you've made. The second is portrait in nature, and it's height/width is making it difficult to fit the container for it.

There's not one set of styles I can see to make both work the way you want (unless you cropped image #2 into a landscape orientation in a graphics editor).

Add some inline CSS styling to your second image (in the HTML):

```
<div class="container">    
    <div class="image-box">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/bMfYu6M.jpg" style="margin-top:-120px;"/>
    </div>
</div>
```

This did the trick for me.

If you find you have many 'portrait-style' images like this, then it may be worth your while creating a class in your CSS like .img-portrait or something, and apply it to the ones you're having trouble with, to save you from all the inline styling you'd need to do:

Like `<img src="http://i.imgur.com/bMfYu6M.jpg" class="img-portrait">` or something similar.

Comment: A more generic version of the css would be: margin-top:-50%;

Comment: This worked great for the second image, but if I apply the same inline style to the first image, it moves the image almost completely out of the container.

Comment: Then don't add it to the first image. That's the beauty of inline styling. It applies only to the elements you apply it to.

Comment: That's true.  There is a bit more behind the question.  I didn't want to confuse the issue I was having, but there will be 12 images per page in a 3x4 grid generated from a database query, so I wanted to be able to use the same code for every image. When I loop through the URLs, I can generate the code for each result automatically.  If I just had a few static images, your solution would have been great.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use the image as a background for your `.image-box` rather than including an `<img>` tag as a child of the `.image-box`. You'd just need to set:

- `background-image: url(blah);`
- `background-size: 100%;`
- `background-position: center center;`

However, the resulting HTML isn't as clean as it will probably require some inline styles which are generally not the best.

A [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/66aw9/).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  I had seen where background-image was used in a couple other examples, but it looked messy.  If this is what it comes to though, I will go down this route.